# How to prove $A\subseteq B \wedge C:=\lbrace x:x\in A\wedge x\in B\rbrace \longrightarrow C=A$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

How may I prove that such a statement if *set operations* are yet to be defined in my course (Introductory Proof-Writing).

My questions:

$1$. Is my proof alright?

$2$ May you give any alternative proofs taking into account we have not defined set operations in my course?

Here's my attempt:

**Proof.**

We need to show $A=C$ or $$A\subseteq C \wedge C\subseteq A$$

Let's notice that from our hypotheis we have $x\in C \longleftrightarrow x\in A \wedge x\in B$, which is logically equivalent to $$C\subseteq A \wedge C\subseteq B$$

Remains for us to prove $A\subseteq C$ and to that end let $a\in A$.

By way of contradiction suppose that $a\notin C$. This implies $a\notin A \vee a\notin B$.

Because $a\in A$, $a\notin B$. A contradiction to the fact $A\subseteq B$. Thus, the statement is true.

Comment: Just to verify, please clarify whether the question's title represents $(A\subseteq B) \wedge C$ or $A\subseteq (B \wedge C).$

Comment: ($A\subseteq C$ ) $\wedge C$

Comment: "Let's notice that from our hypotheis we have $x\in C \longleftrightarrow x\in A \wedge x\in B$".  I am confused by this.  Why does $x \in C$ imply that $x \in (A \cap B)$?  For example, it isn't immediately clear to me that you can't have $x \in C$ and simultaneously that $A$ is not a subset of $B$.  While you may be able to prove that you can't have both situations simultaneously, I don't see how that you can start off assuming it.  Perhaps I am overlooking something.